# Alert Crashes View

Tags: swift, if-statement, button, swiftui

I am using a navigation link and 2 buttons on the basis of some conditions. The problem is when i first click a button, alert appears but when I click on any button again, the view crashes. Can't see the problem. Can anyone help?
Also, is there a better way to write this code?

```
               @State private var showAlertToDownload: Bool = false
               @State private var showAlertToCompletePriorLevels: Bool = false

                LazyVStack (spacing: 25){
                ForEach(Array(indexElementsArray.enumerated()), id: \.0) {index, item 
                in
                    
                    let ifButtonDisabled = coreDataHelper.checkIfButtonDisabled(levelName: "Level\(index + 1)")
                    let ifLevelUnlocked = coreDataHelper.checkIfLevelUnlocked(levelName: "Level\(index + 1)")
                    
                    if ifButtonDisabled && ifLevelUnlocked{
                        NavigationLink {
                            ChapterListView(heading: "Lesson \(index+1) - \(item.level)", index: index)
                        } label: {
                            IndexCard(lessonNumber: index, heading: item.level, image: item.image, bgColor: item.bgColor)
                        }
                        
                    }else if !ifButtonDisabled{
                        Button {
                            showAlertToDownload.toggle()
                        } label: {
                            IndexCard(lessonNumber: index, heading: item.level, image: item.image, bgColor: item.bgColor)
                        }
                        .alert(isPresented: $showAlertToDownload) {
                            Alert(
                                title: Text("Download Data"),
                                message: Text("Please download the data before accessing this lesson."),
                                dismissButton: .default(Text("OK"))
                            )
                        }
                    }else{
                        Button {
                            showAlertToCompletePriorLevels.toggle()
                        } label: {
                            IndexCard(lessonNumber: index, heading: item.level, image: item.image, bgColor: item.bgColor)
                        }
                        .alert(isPresented: $showAlertToCompletePriorLevels) {
                            Alert(
                                title: Text("Complete Prior Levels"),
                                message: Text("Please complete the prior levels before accessing this lesson."),
                                dismissButton: .default(Text("OK"))
                            )
                        }
                    }
                    
                    
                }
            }//LazyVStack
```

Comment: What does " the view breaks" mean? You say that in the question and in the title you say it "crashes". Also, you should include a [mre] -- no on  can run the code you've included.

Comment: View breaks mean that the view crashes. Chatgpt says the the problem might me that it tries to show two alerts and crashes the view, but I cant understand how.

Comment: What does Xcode say the error is when it crashes?

Comment: The crash report indicates that my application crashed due to a segmentation fault (SIGSEGV) with the Exception Code EXC_BAD_ACCESS. See its a crash report hence it is very big. If it's cool, I can show u over zoom or teams.

Comment: You could try moving both `.alert(...)` outside the `ForEach` loop.
As mentioned you should show a minimal reproducible code that produces your issue, see: [minimal code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)